# Tuples of arrays 1D and 2D to dataframe with python

Tags: python, tuples

This is what a model.predic returns. ¿How can i convert this tuple in columns of a dataframe?

```
(array([1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]), array([[0.46502338, 0.53497662],
        [0.47072865, 0.52927135],
        [0.4696557 , 0.5303443 ],
        ...,
        [0.47139825, 0.52860175],
        [0.46367829, 0.53632171],
        [0.46586898, 0.53413102]]))
<class 'tuple'>
```

Nothing of those is working for me

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(class_pred=tuple[0], prob_0=tuple[1], prob_1=tuple[2]))
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(tuple),columns=['class_pred','prob_0','prob_1'])
```

I would like to obtain something like this:

```
class_pred  prob_0    prob_1
1           0.470728  0.5292713
```

AniSkywalker solution works perfectly.

```
type(data)
print(data)

tuple
(array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]),
 array([[0.46502338, 0.53497662],
        [0.47072865, 0.52927135],
        [0.4696557 , 0.5303443 ],
        [0.46511921, 0.53488079],
        [0.46739934, 0.53260066],
        [0.47387646, 0.52612354],
        [0.4737461 , 0.5262539 ],
        [0.47052631, 0.52947369],
        [0.47658316, 0.52341684],
        [0.47222654, 0.52777346]]))
```

```py
df_pred = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(pred=data[0], prob_0=data[1][:,0], prob_1=data[1][:,1]))
```

```
print(df_pred)

    pred    prob_0      prob_1
0   1.0     0.465023    0.534977
1   1.0     0.470729    0.529271
2   1.0     0.469656    0.530344
3   1.0     0.465119    0.534881
4   1.0     0.467399    0.532601
5   1.0     0.473876    0.526124
6   1.0     0.473746    0.526254
7   1.0     0.470526    0.529474
8   1.0     0.476583    0.523417
9   1.0     0.472227    0.527773
```

Comment: what is the shape of this output array?

Comment: The only difference between your working solution and mine is that I specified `data` as a keyword argument, while you passed it as a positional argument. Please note that the first line, where you specify the column names, does not actually do anything, since you assign to `df` with another DataFrame anyways. The column names work out because they are also the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: By the way, if you found the solution please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was my fault, i couldn't mark it yesterday. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your data is of the form `((n), (n, 2))` so that:

```py
import numpy as np
n = 5
data = (np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n, 2))
```

provides a reasonable estimate of what your output looks like.

Let's say that `data` is:

```py
(array([0.27856312, 0.66255123, 0.47976175, 0.59381106, 0.82096555]), array([[0.53719357, 0.55803381],
       [0.5749893 , 0.09712089],
       [0.91607789, 0.21579499],
       [0.50163898, 0.39188127],
       [0.60427654, 0.07801227]]))
```

Your `dict` method actually works with one modification:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(class_pred=data[0], prob_0=data[1][:,0], prob_1=data[1][:,1]))
```

Notice that `prob_0` and `prob_1` are both derived from the second tuple element, but using Numpy's column indexing we can split the individual arrays as you described.

Let's take `data[1][:,0]`, for example: first, we select the second element of the `data` tuple, which is the `(n, 2)` matrix. Then, we select the first column (`0`) from all rows (`:`). The result is a vector of the first element of every row in that matrix.

Using my made-up numbers, `df.head()` should give you:

```
   class_pred    prob_0    prob_1
0    0.278563  0.537194  0.558034
1    0.662551  0.574989  0.097121
2    0.479762  0.916078  0.215795
3    0.593811  0.501639  0.391881
4    0.820966  0.604277  0.078012
```

Comment: Side-note: I don't think you can have a variable called tuple, since that would overload the builtin `tuple` constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much AniSkywalker, your solution is not working for me, i got this error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data2'

Comment: I've just update my question with the error an alternative solution.

Comment: The parameter for DataFrame is data, not data2. Change `pd.Dataframe(data2=` to `pd.DataFrame(data=`